# find white space in strings

Tags: java, string

I want to take each character of a string and place it into a stack, skipping whitespace, punctuation, and converting all characters to lowercase. The case part I got fine, but I am trying to figure out how to catch only the characters of the word. How do Strings work with finding what char is at a specific index? Is there something similar to `array[0]` where you can easily capture the object in a specific reference? Any suggestions? I thought about trying to do something along the lines of:

```
while ([string at index i] == " " [null?]) {
    i++;
}
```

But I don't think that works and have no idea how to go about that. Anyone that can help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Read the javadoc of the `String` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String`'s [`replaceAll(s,s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function to eliminate all whitespace characters:

```
String strWithNoWhitespace = strWithWhitespace.replaceAll("\s", "");
```

If you only want to delete spaces and tabs, and not new-lines, you can use

```
String strWithNoSpacesOrTabs = strWithWhitespace.replaceAll("[ \t]", "");
```

Comment: and would that basically just concatenate the string?

Comment: Yes. It eliminates all whitespace, collapsing the rest of the string together into a new string.

Answer (score 2):

There are much easier ways to replace whitespace. But since you asked for a way to obtain a character at a certain position, you can use:

```
str.charAt(i);
```

[JavaDoc for charAt(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

Comment: so if I wanted to add that to a stack, would doing something like `stack.add(str.charAt(i))` work?

Comment: Yeah, for this you would need a `Stack` of `Character`s, for example: 
`Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>()`, you can then add to the stack with standard stack operations, such as 
`stack.push(str.charAt(0))` and `stack.pop()`

Answer (score 1):

To return the character at a certain place in the string, you would use:

```
nameOfString.charAt(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just turn the string into a `char[]` (array of characters) with the [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method. After than you can use the `Character` class's utility methods to check for whitespace and convert things to lowercase.

```
Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<Character>();
for (char c : inputString.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
        stack.push(Character.toLowerCase(c));
    }
}
```